# The norm of a multilinear transformation between finite-dimensional vector spaces is always finite

Tags: vector-spaces, normed-spaces

I am studying n-linear maps from Zorich, Mathematical analysis II, p. 49-53, where the author writes that "it is not difficult to prove that for mappings of finite-dimensional spaces the norm of a multilinear transformation is always finite".
I am trying to do it myself, starting from the simple case of a linear $ A: X \to Y $ map between any two normed vector spaces $ X $ and $ Y $.

All I can write is:

$$||A||:=\sup_{|x|_X=1}|A(x)|_Y=\sup_{|x|_X=1}|A(x^1e_1+...+x^me_m)|_Y=\sup_{|x|_X=1}|x^1A(e_1)+...+x^mA(e_m)|_Y \leq \sup_{|x|_X=1} |x^1|\cdot |A(e_1)|_Y+...+|x^m|\cdot |A(e_m)|_Y\leq (|A(e_1)|_Y+...+|A(e_m)|_Y)\sup_{|x|_X=1} \max_{i=1,...,m} |x^i|$$

where $||\cdot||$ indicates the norm of a multilinear map, $|\cdot|_X$ and $|\cdot|_Y$ indicate the norm of a vector in space $X$ and $Y$, $(e_1,...,e_m)$ is a basis for $X$.

I can't conclude by finding a reason (in the general case we are considering) why $ \max_{i = 1, ..., m} | x^i | $ should be a limited quantity.
Maybe this is a stupid question, but I can't find a general reason.

Comment: It is much easier to think about this by noticing that the set $\{|x|_X = 1\}$ is a closed, bounded set in a finite dimensional normed space, and hence is compact. The function $A(x)$ is continuous on the space. A continuous function attains its finite maximum on a compact set.

Comment: Have you learnt about equivalence of norms? Because taking the maximum of the components defines a norm on $X$; let's call it $|\cdot|_{\text{max}}$. But since all norms on finite-dimensional spaces are equivalent, there is a $C>0$ such that $|\cdot|_{\text{max}} \leq C |\cdot|_X$. Thus, if you restrict attention to $|x|_X \leq 1$, you'll see that the maximum is indeed a bounded quantity (bounded above by $C$ in fact).

Comment: @WillieWong, please could you give me a reference where I can study the fact that in any normed vector space a set is compact iff it is bounded and closed? The only proposition that I know is this "A set K in a metric space (X,d) is compact iff from any sequence of points in K one can extract a subsequence that converges to a point in K". With this last proposition I can't prove the claim, because I have difficulties showing that if a given sequence is composed by an infinite number of points in K, then there is a limit point in K.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Unfortunately no, I've not yet studied "equivalence of norms". Have you any reference?

Comment: The proof is actually pretty simple. First we prove it on $\Bbb{R}^n$ as follows: let $\rho$ be any norm, and let $|\cdot|$ be the Euclidean norm. Prove by a direct $\epsilon,\delta$ estimate that $\rho$ is a continuous function on $\Bbb{R}^n$ (with respect to $|\cdot|$). Since the sphere $S^{n-1}$ is compact in $\Bbb{R}^n$ (the topology being the one induced by the Euclidean norm), it follows that $\rho$ attains a strictly positive maximum and minimum on the sphere, say $M$ and $m$ respectively. So, for all $x \in \Bbb{R}^n$, we have $m|x| \leq \rho(x) \leq M|x|$. THis completes the proof.

Comment: For equivalence of norms on general vector spaces, simply use a linear isomorphism to reduce to the $\Bbb{R}^n$ case. Anyway, one reference I know of is Henri Cartan's Differential Calculus text (page 16-17), another is Loomis and Sternberg's Advanced Calculus (availabe online, see page 208). Otherwise, just google the theorem; it's fairly standard so you should be able to find without too much trouble.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I found this useful link: https://math.mit.edu/~stevenj/18.335/norm-equivalence.pdf and so I learned that in my inequality chain I can conclude simply saying that $\max_{i=1,...,m}|x^i|$ is a norm, so it is equivalent to $|\cdot |_X$, and so $\sup_{|x|_X=1} \max_{i=1,...,m}|x^i|\leq c\cdot \sup_{|x|_X=1} |x|_X=c\cdot 1 = c$. Right?

Comment: Extension to multilinear transformation: 
$$||A||:=\sup_{|x_1|=1,...,|x_n|=1}|A(x_1,...,x_n)|=\sup_{|x_1|=1,...,|x_n|=1}|\sum_{i_1=1}^{m_1}...\sum_{i_n=1}^{m_n}A(e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_n})x_1^{i_1}x_2^{i_2}...x_n^{i_n}|\leq \sum_{i_1=1}^{m_1}...\sum_{i_n=1}^{m_n}|A(e_{i_1},e_{i_2},...,e_{i_n})|\sup_{|x_1|=1,...,|x_n|=1}\max_{i_1}|x_1^{i_1}|\max_{i_1}|x_2^{i_2}|...\max_{i_n}x_n^{i_n}$$ and so in the same way as in the $n=1$ (linear map) case...

Comment: yes, you're right in the linear case. I didn't really check the multilinear case too carefully, but it seems to be on the right track.